# Nodejs Buffer: How to read out bit flags?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, binary, buffer

I am listening on data events on a tcp socket.

Each data event provides me a buffer which is a frame of a protocol.
The first byte works as header and contains some bit flags I would like to access.

Until there listening on data events and getting the first byte looks as:

```
socket.on('data', function(buff) {
    console.log(buff[0]); // returns 129
});
```

If I now want to check the first bit then I must transform the 129 to bit format and then check out the first number.

```
129 => 1000 0001
       |
```

As we know JavaScript does not support binaries.

I am now wondering if the node buffer object allows me to work bit wise and if yes how this would look like?

Regards

Comment: There are bitwise operators in JavaScript.

Comment: @pimvdb I know but how could they help me about this example? Could you provide an example?

Comment: MDN has a great refence for bitwise operators: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking a flag can be done using the `&` operator.

For a flag that does contain the first bit:

```
1000 0001      129
1000 0000      128
--------- &
1000 0000      128
```

For a flag that doesn't contain the first bit:

```
0101 0001      81
1000 0000      128
--------- &
0000 0000      0
```

So the result is either the flag (if the flag has been set) or zero (if the flag has not been set). Hence, you could create a function (where `flag` is a power of 2):

```
var containsFlag = function(number, flag) {
  return (number & flag) === flag;
};

containsFlag(129, 128);  // true
containsFlag(81, 128);   // false
```

Comment: is it actually better to use for example ascii instead of dezimal encoding for such check?

Comment: @kyogron: What do you mean?

Comment: it would also be possible to do a (0x2 & 0xA) == 0x2 (so just with hexadecimal values). Is there any performance hint to use a specific encoding over another?

Comment: @kyogron: `0x2` represents exactly the same number as `2`. Both can be represented as a plain integer, so calculations should be just as fast.